# What is the best practice to get the context of subsite?

Tags: provider-hosted-app, adfs, spcontext

I have created a provider hosted app with adfs. In this app I have the SP  clientContext of the site collection. I have a form in this app. When the user submits the form, there will be created a subsite.

```
// Set the clientcontext for the SPHost
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext clientContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(HttpContext.Current).CreateUserClientContextForSPHost();

// Create new subsite
Web newWeb = clientContext.Web.CreateWeb(new OfficeDevPnP.Core.Entities.SiteEntity()
            {
                Title = "subsite1",
                Url = "subsite1",
                Description = "subsite1",
                Template = "BLANKINTERNET#0",
                Lcid = (uint)1043
            }, true, true);
```

After creating "subsite1" I would like to create a second subsite under "subsite1". But I need first to get the client context of "subsite1".

How can I get the client context of an spweb? Maybe by url?

**UPDATE**

I am trying now to open the subsite1 and create a subsite2 under subsite1. I got the exception:

> Ensure that this object or its parent (such as an SPWeb or SPSite) is
>   being properly disposed. This object is holding on to a separate
>   native heap.

And this is the stacktrace:

```
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponseStream(Stream responseStream)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponse()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContextExtensions.ExecuteQueryImplementation(ClientRuntimeContext clientContext, Int32 retryCount, Int32 delay)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WebExtensions.CreateWeb(Web parentWeb, String title, String leafUrl, String description, String template, Int32 language, Boolean inheritPermissions, Boolean inheritNavigation)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WebExtensions.CreateWeb(Web parentWeb, SiteEntity subsite, Boolean inheritPermissions, Boolean inheritNavigation)
   at CompanyName.SharePoint.ProvisioningWeb.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in E:\VSO\CompanyName\Main\CompanyName\CompanyName.SharePoint.ProvisioningWeb\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 38
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
```

Here is the code:

```
[SharePointContextFilter]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            User spUser = null;

            var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(HttpContext);

            using (var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
            {
                if (clientContext != null)
                {
                    spUser = clientContext.Web.CurrentUser;

                    clientContext.Load(spUser, user => user.Title);

                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    ViewBag.UserName = spUser.Title;

                    /////////////////////

                    var subweb1 = clientContext.Site.OpenWeb("sub1");
                    clientContext.Load(subweb1);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQueryRetry();

                    // Create new subsite
                    Web sub2 = subweb1.CreateWeb(new OfficeDevPnP.Core.Entities.SiteEntity()
                    {
                        Title = "sub2",
                        Url = "sub2",
                        Description = "sub2", // todo, deze beschrijving wordt niet opgeslagen in de site
                        Template = "BLANKINTERNET#0",
                        Lcid = (uint)1043
                    }, true, true);

                    // Load the url property (office dev extension method)
                    sub2.EnsureProperty(w => w.Url);

                    string sub2Title = sub2.Title;
                }
            }

            return View();
        }
```

Comment: If your issue is resolved, please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted and upvote if you find the answer helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to construct `web` object using `OpenWeb` method like this:

```
var subweb = clientContext.Site.OpenWeb("subsite1");
clientContext.Load(subweb);
clientContext.ExecuteQueryRetry();
```

Later you can you use `subweb` in order to create a new site.

Comment: I try this solution. But when I try to create subsite2 I got this exception: Ensure that this object or its parent (such as an SPWeb or SPSite) is being properly disposed. This object is holding on to a separate native heap.

Comment: Are you using server side object model?

Comment: no, this is an provider hosted app. Only CSOM and pnp

Comment: Can you please post stack trace of the exception?

Comment: See update for the stacktrace

Comment: Are you on-premise? If yes, please take a look [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepointdevelopersupport/2016/10/19/fixing-error-the-request-uses-too-many-resources-in-csom-rest-operation/) and try to set `$webApp.ClientCallableSettings.MaxResourcesPerRequest` to a higher number

Comment: this works, but why is this needed?

Comment: The answer is in the article I sent - _However, in some cases a single atomic CSOM operation will throw this error. This may happen in case of activating a feature which creates a lot of SPRequest objects or when provisioning a sub site using CSOM/REST._ That is exactly your issue.